How do I automate the process when external display is connected
I work in a hot desk environment. Whenever I come to the office I sit at an available desk and plug my computer in.
The problem is that everytime I do this I have to change display settings to extend the desktop and rearrange the monitors to my desired configuration.
I am looking for a way to automate this so that when the computer detects external monitors plugged in, it will automatically do the previously mentioned steps.
I tried power automate record, but it doesn't record when the displays are plugged in (as the trigger). Similarly not sure if task scheduler does this or how.
Any help is appreciated!
